# How to achieve result of a 2 Layer setup(top one is Overlay blend) with a multiple default images combination?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, color-theory, adobe-after-effects, blend-modes

Imagine we have a 2 layer setup like this:

Top Layer + (Blend Mode: Overlay)
this layer shows a half-transparent smoke cloud - very bright in the center starting at white with smooth color transitions to yellow to red to transparent.
You can see the lower layer through this top layer when top layer is visible.

Bottom Layer + (Blend Mode: default)
this layer shows a bright monochrome background image - a long floor with textured walls(2D side-scroller perspective)

Now we could merge both into a single layer with a Copy from Visible event and get the same result - only when Blend mode was in Overlay before this turned into a single image of course.
But is there also an alternative setup without using special Blend modes at all, but with multiple images?
Imagine the two requirements for that setup would be:

1. Multiple images(2-3 images; the background image would be one of the 2or3 and you are not allowed to modify it in any way)
2. No special Blend Mode active(just normal image mode)

How could such a setup with the above or a similar type of graphics arrangement look like?
What kind of images do we must combine with the background drawing for the same result(the result that worked before - with 2 images + one special Blend mode active: Overlay)

(bold text below edited - I accidently wrote "only 100% opaque pixels"):
**Perhaps there is a 2 image combination possible where the 2nd image is an extraction of the background layer that only consists of color pixels? (!with various degrees of transparency!)**

Comment: It must be possible yes, but seldom used I guess as there is no real advantage to just having the merged layer. The top layer would have to be placed exactly in the right spot to look as intended, you wouldn't be able to move it around.

Comment: Any chance you could you possibly post an example image showing what you are trying to do or what has failed?

Comment: Actually, thinking more about it, the merged layer already satisfies what you ask for: it's an image you can place on top of the bottom layer to make it look like the top layer was applied with overlay blend mode. It just doesn't have any transparency. I think you have to explain *why* you want to do this.